# C#: Could you explain how TaskFactory executes asynchronously method which is passed as a parameter to StartNew method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool

I have a problem with understanding of execution of asynchronously method which is passed as a parameter to `StartNew` method of `TaskFactory`. Could you explain me how exactly it will work?

I have `UserInfo` class which contains user identifier.

```
public sealed class UserInfo
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        public static Guid UserId;
    }
```

I have my custom implementation of `TaskScheduler`. I don't show a full code of this class because it isn't interesting. This class set user identifier to current thread. Set user identifier to `UserId` variable.

```
public sealed class CustomTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
    {
        // Sets user information to the variable which is marked ThreadStatisAttribute.
    }
```

I created my custom `TaskFactory` which takes custom scheduler as a parameter of constructor.

```
public sealed class CustomTaskFactory : TaskFactory
    {
        public CustomTaskFactory(CustomTaskScheduler taskScheduler) : base(taskScheduler) { }
    }
```

And finally I have the `Service` class which performs asynchronously operations.

```
public sealed class Service
    {
        private readonly CustomTaskScheduler customTaskScheduler;
        private readonly CustomTaskFactory customTaskFactory;
        private readonly SomeClient someClient;

        public Service()
        {
            this.customTaskScheduler = new CustomTaskScheduler();
            this.customTaskFactory = new CustomTaskFactory(this.customTaskScheduler);
            this.someClient = new SomeClient();
        }

        public void DoSomething(string param)
        {
            this.customTaskFactory.StartNew(() => testAsync(param)).Unwrap().Wait();

            // This method will use the result which is given by async operation which is called above.
            DoSomethingElseSynchronously();
        }

        private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            int result1 = await this.customTaskFactory.StartNew(() => PerformAsyncOperation(default(int))).Unwrap();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            int result2 = await this.customTaskFactory.StartNew(() => PerformAsyncOperation(default(int))).Unwrap();

            int sum = result1 + result2;
        }

        private async Task<int> PerformAsyncOperation(int x)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            return await this.customTaskFactory.StartNew(() => CallClientAsync(x)).Unwrap();
        }

        private async Task<int> CallClientAsync(int x)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            int resultObtainedFromClient1 = await this.customTaskFactory.StartNew(async () => await this.someClient.GetAsync(x)).Unwrap();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            int resultObtainedFromClient2 = await this.customTaskFactory.StartNew(async () => await this.someClient.GetAsync(x)).Unwrap();

            int result = resultObtainedFromClient1 + resultObtainedFromClient2;

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Well, to be fair, I have two questions:

1. What is the difference between calls `await this.customTaskFactory.StartNew(async () => await this.someClient.GetAsync(x)).Unwrap()` and `await this.customTaskFactory.StartNew(() => this.someClient.GetAsync(x)).Unwrap()` I would like to recall that I am interested in my `ThreadStatic` variable `UserId`. As I understand the first call will be executed in the same thread which called `StartNew` method and my thread static field will be filled in this case. In the second call I puts asynchronous method as a parameter of `StartNew` method. That means that task will contain asynchronous method which maybe will be executed by another thread and this another thread will not contain my `UserId` variable.

   2. I need to be sure that each thread will contain not empty `UserId` variable. Are there any cases when I lose `UserId` data? How to prevent it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, if you're using `async`/`await`, you *shouldn't* also be *manually* creating `Task`s - you're just confusing things because the `async` machinery is creating the `Task`s that those methods return. Any tasks that you manually create are likely to just be wrapping other tasks and will frequently have different lifetimes.

Comment: Yes, you are 100% right, but I need to be sure that my `UserId` variable is initialized in each thread. When I use `async/await` constructions I don't know when and how many threads will be created and executed. That means that I need to check or set `UserId` variable before each `async/await`. It will make my code dirty.